# Unable to send a 404 error using Node.js with express

Tags: node.js

To learn Node.js I'm using VS Code Win10 to create an express Simple Client Request. The problem I'm running into is when I try to send an error 404 the Simple client request returns the text 'object object'. Non-of the attempts to return a not found message works. Can you let me know what is wrong with the below get function

Thanks

```
router.get('/accounts/:user', (req, res) => { 
    const user = req.params.user; 
    console.log('at 2 ' + user);  **<<-- works**
    const account = db[user];
    if (!account) {
        console.log(user + ' does not exist'); **<<-- works**
        return res.json('user  does not exist'); **<<-- works**
        // return res.status(404).send({ message: 'Route'+req.url+' Not found.' }); **<<-- does not works**
        return res.status(404).json(  { error: 'user  does not exist'}    ); **<<-- does not works**
    }
    return res.json(account);   **<<-- works**
});
```

Comment: you should have received an error stating something like `you are attempting to set the status header after response is sent to client`

Comment: I don't follow what you mean.  when is the status to be sent? the the function the line which does not work is ' return res.status(404).send('user  does not exist');' router.get('/accounts/:user', (req, res) => { 
    const user = req.params.user; 
    const account = db[user];
    if (!account) {
        return res.status(404).send('user  does not exist'); 
    }
    return res.json(account); 
});

Comment: I'm saying the function is being returned on line `return res.json('user  does not exist');` so line `return res.status(404).json(  { error: 'user  does not exist'}    );` is not being called. And if you remove the `return` from previous line you will get the `attempting to set status after response is sent` error

Comment: with 404 errors the client expects the message response to be of type string. If you respond with `json({ error: '....'})` the client reads an object (the `json`) and in that another object (`error`), so outputs `object object`. Use `.send('message')` like in the answer below

Comment: return res.status(404).send('user  does not exist');  **<<-- does not work**

Comment: Can you post the client side code that is calling this route?

Comment: The image the found and not found image have been uploaded to postimage.org https://postimg.cc/gallery/z855xh2

Comment: just to be clear, the screenshot if result of this line `return res.status(404).send('user does not exist');` ?

Comment: try going to 'http://localhost:5000/api/accounts/nobody` in a browser vs the extension you're currently using.

Comment: the screen shot is a result of  return res.status(404).send('user does not exist'); and various iterations of for example replace replacing 'send' with 'json' and adding 'message': or 'error' before the text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241762/discussion-between-knicholas-and-sal).

Answer (score 1):

```
router.get('/accounts/:user', (req, res) => { 
    const user = req.params.user; 
    console.log('at 2 ' + user);  **<<-- works**
    const account = db[user];
    if (!account) {
        console.log(user + ' does not exist'); **<<-- works**
        return res.status(404).send('user  does not exist'); **<<-- works**
    }
    return res.json(account);   **<<-- works**
});
```